# Smart Switch Wiring Neutral Wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

[image]Would anyone know what is the best way to wire my 3 smart switches. 2 of them are single pole, 1 of them is a 4 way switch, there are only 2 bundles of neutral (see picture) how would I wire 3 Switches to 2 bundles, all 3 smart switches need a neutral wire, any ideas? Sorry but I'm a newbie to this. I have wired a separate smart switch to another location of home, but it was simple since it was only one switch in box. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What are you using for a smart switch?  Are you replacing the other switches in the four-way complex?

Comment: Are these all on one circuit? I'd be cautious that the bundle of two white might NOT be neutral, despite being white. Got a voltmeter?

Answer (score 4):

A "cable" is several "wires" wrapped in a sheath.

In order to get neutral to a smart switch, you must follow the cardinal rule.  Note the (hot) wires already attached to the switch.  Note which cable(s) those hot wires come from.  **You can only take neutral from those same cables that hots come from**.

You have two totally separate groups of neutral.  You must follow the wires and take the smart switch neutral only from the bundle associated with those hots.

On the 4-way switch, you will not be putting a smart switch here.  There are at least 3 switches controlling that light.  You will need to open them up and look at the wiring layout present at those switches. That wiring will *dictate to you* which one to replace with a smart switch, if that is even possible.

Comment: Thanks, I take that back, It's gonna be 2 single pole smart switches, and 1 regular 4 way switch with no neutral to match the look of the 2 smart switches.

Comment: @ArtSoto As long as the smart-switch instructions tell you to wire it that way.